# log4j2 configuration empty log files

Tags: log4j2

the following `log4j2` configuration always results in empty log files and everything getting written to console. I don't want anything on the console except for the errors. Could you please help me give a hint on where I am going wrong?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="TRACE" name="MyApp">
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="logs/app.log"
                     filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}-%i.log" immediateFlush="true">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="60"/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="950 MB"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="DataRollingFile" fileName="logs/data.log"
                     filePattern="logs/completed/data-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}-%i.log" immediateFlush="true">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="60"/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="250 MB"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
        <!--<Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">-->
        <!--<PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>-->
        <!--</Console>-->
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.myapp.xdf.mimic" level="WARN"/>
        <Logger name="org.springframework" level="ERROR"/>
        <Logger name="com.myapp.xdf.mimic.adapter.DataWriter" level="WARN" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="DataRollingFile"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration has the Console appender commented out so it shouldn't be possible to have any logs directed to it. Are you sure your configuration is being read? Since you have trace enabled you should see logs generated when it is processed.